# FindRoot inside Flatten Table

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I want to evaluate a function that depends on parameters and on another function that, by its turn, also depend on the same parameters.

For example, let's say I have f(x(a,b);a,b), where a and b are parameters and x is also a function of a and b. I know ideally I could just substitute x(a,b) in f so f is only a function of a and b but my problem is more complicated as x(a,b) is the zero of a function. What I mean is that I can't solve x for a and b and plug into f.

But I want to calculate the value of the function for ranges of a and b. Just to avoid confusions, let's say a is in the interval [0.1,1] and b is in the interval [1.1,2]. The code below doesn't work, of course, but it tries to show my problem:

```
        Xfunction=-a/(a-0.5*x)^2+b/(b-0.25*x)^2;
        f[a_, b_, Xfunction] := a + b+Xfunction;
        fimage = Flatten[Table[{a, b, x(a,b), f[a, b, x(a,b)]}, {a, 0.1, 1}, {b, 1.1, 2}, 
    {FindRoot[Xfunction == 0, {x, 0.01}]}], 2];
```

What I want to do is to have the Table with all values of f for the specified range of a and b, which requires that the zero of Xfunction is found for each combination of a and b.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Just to make sure. You want to evaluate a function `f(a,b,x)` wherer `x` is the root of another function `g` in  `(a,b)`. You last sentence is confusing. Do you want to find all `a`,`b` where `Xfunction` has a root or do you want to evaluate

Comment: It is indeed confusing. I want to evaluate f for many values of a and b but to do that I need first to find the root of g that also depends on a and b. Is that better? I think I found a way now but I am not 100% secure.

Comment: I think in my example above the problem can be easily solved like this. Call g(a,b) the X function. Then, Table[f[i,j, g /. FindRoot[g[i,j], {g, 0.01}]], {i, 0.1, 1,0.1},{j, 1.1, 2, 0.1}]

Comment: I guess you want $g(x,a,b)$ because then you can calculate $x$ values where $g(x,a,b)=0$. Then it should be `x/.FindRoot[g[x,a,b],{x,0.01}]`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much everyone! It was easier than I thought.